# Scraping Google Keyword Tools with CasperJS and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm currently trying to scrape Google Keyword Tools with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) and PhantomJS (both excellent tools, thanks n1k0 and Ariya), but I can't get it to work.

Here is my current process:

1. Log in with my Google Account (to avoid captchas in the Keyword Tools).
2. Navigate to the Keyword Tools page.
3. Fill in the search form and press `Search`.

I'm stuck at step 3: the search form is not a regular HTML form, I can't use `Casper#fill()`, so instead I'm accessing the fields directly. Here are some of the syntaxes I tried to change the value of the `Word or phrase` field:

```
this.evaluate(function() {

    // Trying to change the value...
    document.querySelector('textarea.sP3.sBFB').value = 'MY SUPER KEYWORDS';
    document.querySelector('textarea.sP3.sBFB').setAttribute('value', 'MY SUPER KEYWORDS');
    document.querySelector('textarea').value = 'MY SUPER KEYWORDS';   // there's only one <textarea> on the page

    // Trying to change other attributes...
    document.querySelector('textarea.sP3.sBFB').textContent = 'MY SUPER KEYWORDS';
    document.querySelector('textarea').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
});
```

Nothing works. I'm doing a `Casper#capture()` right after to see what the field contains. [As you can see](http://i42.tinypic.com/9apf2s.png), it confirms I am on the right page and that I am logged in, but the `<textarea>` is empty.

Strangely, I can access other parts of the DOM: I could change the text of a link that said `Advanced Options and Filters` to `___VINCE SAYS HELLO___` (see capture), by doing the following:

```
this.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector('a.sLAB').textContent = '___VINCE SAYS HELLO___';
});
```

PS. I know scraping Google Keyword Tools is against the TOS, but I'm thinking this question might be of interest to anyone trying to scrape a JavaScript/Ajax-heavy site.

Comment: You probably have to wait for this textarea to be loaded and available. Checkout out the [documentation for waitForSelector()](http://casperjs.org/#phantom_Casper_waitForSelector)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, NiKo.
I did already try your suggestion. In fact, the code you're seeing up here is enclosed within a `WaitFor()` statement. I tried a `WaitForSelector('textarea.sP3.sBFB')` and also a `WaitFor()` with a function testing the existence of the field thanks to `__utils__.exists()`, but neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('textarea.sP3.sBFB').value = 'MY SUPER KEYWORDS';
```

You can't use `elt.value` on a textarea. Did you try with `elt.textContent`?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try to scrape the results. Google already creating a csv file for us. 
Try downloading that. That links selector must be like $('.gux-combo gux-dropdown-c .sJK')
Will you use that for automating things ?

Comment: What CSV file? it's just pipe dream. Such a thing is like unicorns! Doesn't exist.

Comment: Please go and investigate adwords keywords panel there is a hidden -not anymore hidden- section where you can retrieve all keyword combinations triggered your ads. It's a gold mine for me.

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı what section do you mean? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's happening here, but the classes that you're using for targeting are different for me.  The `OneBoxKeywordsInputPanel-input` textarea that I assume you're attempting to target has a second class, `sPFB`, and no other classes.  It's possible that these cryptic classes are dynamic in some way.  I'd recommend using the more descriptive class names instead.  The following works just fine for me:

```
document.querySelector('textarea.OneBoxKeywordsInputPanel-input')
```